# How to take subsample of dataframe with top, middle and bottom percentages in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which basically looks like the following:

```
X1      X2
A       1000
B       976
C       800
.       .
.       .
.       .
X       89
Y       45
Z       26
```

Now, I want to take a  subsample from my dataframe consisting of the top x%, the middle y% and the bottom z% based on the values in the `X2` column. My dataframe is already ordered descending based on `X2`. Currently, I have this code:

```
a  = subset(data, X2 > quantile(X2, prob = 1 - n/100))
```

However, this only returns me the top n% of the dataframe based on the values in `X2`. Does anyone know how to extend this code to get the a subsample with top x%, the middle y% and the bottom z% based on the values in the `X2` column?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the most elegant solution and it's quite basic, but it still does its job. We'll exploit the fact that your dataset is decreasingly ordered according to X2.

In the following line you insert the proportions of the top x% and bottom z% (here 0.2 and 0.3 are just an example, you change them according to your needs)

```
perc_top <- 0.2 ; perc_bottom <- 0.3
```

Then you split the dataset in three parts with these lines of code:

```
n <- nrow(data)
# number of rows for the top dataset
rows_top <- round(perc_top*n) 
# number of rows for the bottom dataset
rows_bottom <- round(perc_bottom*n)
# creation of the three dataset
data_top <- data[1:rows_top,]
data_bottom <- data[(n-rows_bottom+1):n,]
data_middle <- data[-c(1:rows_top, (n-rows_bottom+1):n),]
```